# Nested OR and AND condition with db_select

Tags: database

How can I convert the following query with db_select

```
SELECT *
FROM 'my_table'
WHERE
(condition1 < "value1" AND ((conidition2 > "value2") OR (condition3 < "value3")))
  OR
(condition4 < "value5" AND ((condition6 < "value6") OR (condition7 < "value7")))
```

I am trying with

```
$query = db_select('mytable');

$query->condition(
          db_and()->condition("condition1","value1")
                 ->condition(
                             db_or()->condition("condition2","value2")->condition("condition3","value3")
                             ));
$query->condition(
          db_and()->condition("condition4","value4")
                 ->condition(
                             db_or()->condition("condition5","value5")->condition("condition6","value6")
                             ));

  $query_debugg = $query->__toString();
dpm($query_debugg);
```

issue is with the "AND" in between where is should be "OR", it is expected I know.how can I change it

Output String

```
SELECT 
FROM 
{mytable} mytable
WHERE ( (condition1 = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND( (condition2 = :db_condition_placeholder_1) OR (condition3 = :db_condition_placeholder_2) ))AND( (condition4 = :db_condition_placeholder_3) AND( (condition5 = :db_condition_placeholder_4) OR (condition6 = :db_condition_placeholder_5) ))
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've already tried, and the query string that returns please? At the moment you're just asking for someone to do your work for you, which isn't an appropriate use of the site (it's a shortcut to getting your question closed on pretty much any Stack Exchange site). You've put `db-or` as a tag so you definitely know where to start, just edit the question with details of that code, and the errors you get, and I'm sure you'll get a good answer

Comment: @Mołot yes it is , I made it working seeing the original :), thanks

Comment: @Clive true, I will keep that in mind

Comment: @arpitr if you solved it, you can post a self-answer, can't you? But I think it's a duplicate anyway. Un-downvoted after seeing you actually did put some effort before asking.

Comment: @Mołot I was doing the same little late :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with help of question pointed by @molot I could make it work, here is the code

```
$query = db_select('mytable');
$db_or = db_or();
$db_or->condition(
  db_and()
    ->condition("condition1","value1")
    ->condition(
      db_or()
        ->condition("condition2","value2")
        ->condition("condition3","value3")
));
$db_or->condition(
  db_and()
    ->condition("condition4","value4")
    ->condition(
      db_or()
        ->condition("condition5","value5")
        ->condition("condition6","value6")
));
$query->condition($db_or);

$src = $query->__toString();
dpm($src);
```

and here is the output

```
SELECT 
FROM 
{mytable} mytable
WHERE (( (condition1 = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND( (condition2 = :db_condition_placeholder_1) OR (condition3 = :db_condition_placeholder_2) ))OR( (condition4 = :db_condition_placeholder_3) AND( (condition5 = :db_condition_placeholder_4) OR (condition6 = :db_condition_placeholder_5) )))
```

Comment: inequalities or condition match was neither my concern nor I have added in the code above

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal, conditions are `AND` by default. It's easier to use objects directly, in my opinion:

```
$left_condition = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
$left_condition->condition( ... ); // add what you need

$right_condition = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
$right_condition->condition( ... ); // add what you need

$condition = new DatabaseCondition('OR');
$condition->condition($left_condition);
$condition->condition($right_condition);
```

But you can use `db_and()` and `db_or()` if you prefer.

Comment: Posted an answer as this question appeared high in my Google results for related queries (so fast?! Bad Google!), to prevent disappointed googlers.