# How to do multiple conditions for db_update by using OR condition?

Tags: 7, database

I would like to convert the following UpdateQuery statement to work with multiple conditions by using `OR` instead of the default `AND` condition.

```php
db_update('system')
  ->fields(array('status' => 1))
  ->condition('type', 'theme')
  ->condition('name', 'seven') // OR
  ->condition('name', 'rubik')
  ->execute();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Drupal 7

Yes, it is possible by using [db_or()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_or/7.x) as in the following example.

```
db_update('system')
  ->fields(array('status' => 1))
  ->condition('type', 'theme')
  ->condition(db_or()
    ->condition('name', 'seven')
    ->condition('name', 'rubik')
  )
  ->execute();
```

For `db_select()`, see the answers given in  ["OR" condition in db_select()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/or-condition-in-db-select-in-drupal-7) and [Nested OR and AND condition with db_select](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90038/nested-or-and-and-condition-with-db-select).

#### Drupal 8

You can still use [`db_or()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_or/8.9.x) as in Drupal 7, but it's deprecated in Drupal 8.0.x and removed in Drupal 9.0.0. Instead, a [`\Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Condition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Condition.php/class/Condition/8.9.x) object should be created as in the following code, taken from [`BooleanOperator::queryOpBoolean()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21filter%21BooleanOperator.php/function/BooleanOperator%3A%3AqueryOpBoolean/8.9.x).

```php
if ($this->accept_null) {
  if ($query_operator === self::EQUAL) {
    $condition = (new Condition('OR'))
      ->condition($field, 0, $query_operator)
      ->isNull($field);
  }
  else {
    $condition = (new Condition('AND'))
      ->condition($field, 0, $query_operator)
      ->isNotNull($field);
  }
  $this->query->addWhere($this->options['group'], $condition);
}
```